# How do I find out if connectNative failed or succeeded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-native-messaging

I have managed to connect my extension to our native host:

```
var pulse_tracker_port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.cloudfactory.pulsetracker');
```

but how do I find out if the connection succeeded or not? The value of 'pulse_tracker_report.name' will always be an empty string no matter if the connection succeeded or not.

I also tried to add listeners to find out if the connection succeeded or not but none of these callbacks are being invoked:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port)
{
  console.log('Connected to "Pulse Tracker" @port: ' + port.name);
});

chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function(port)
{
  console.log('Connected to "Pulse Tracker" @port: ' + port.name);
});
```

BTW this won't be invoked either:

```
pulse_tracker_port.onConnect.addListener(function(port)
{
   console.log('Connected to "Pulse Tracker" @port: ' + port.name);
});
```

This is what I get when I try to do so:

```
main.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined
```

onConnectExternal works for cross-extension messaging between extensions but looks like it doesn't work for native message hosting. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.onConnect` and `chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal` are not relevant here, since they notify you about incoming connections, not about state of outgoing connections.

`pulse_tracker_port` is a [`Port` object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port) which does not have `onConnect` property.

What you need to do is to immediately assign a listener to `onDisconnect` event of the port object. If there was a problem with the connection, the listener will be called and `chrome.runtime.lastError` will be set:

```
var pulse_tracker_port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.cloudfactory.pulsetracker');
pulse_tracker_port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() { 
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
  }
});
```

Otherwise, just try to use it, with `.postMessage()` and `.onMessage` event. For `postMessage`, it will throw an error if the port is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks, here's the last error message on my system right now: message
:"Native host has exited." Looks like I will have to keep that native host in a loop

Comment: Depending on your needs, `runtime.sendNativeMessage` (that runs the host anew every time) may serve you better.

Comment: I got it but in our current project, we should keep running it to do some tasks in a certain interval. Thanks a lot :)